# Can't change UITableViewCell size in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

Does anyone have the same problem as I do? ... I've upgraded to the iPhone SDK 3.2 and I am unable to resize UITableViewCell object in my XIB file (usually I've been just resizing the view but now the cell has the same size and there is just a grey are around) ... btw, I've tried to reinstall twice including one deep reinstall.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615862/custom-cell-row-height-setting-in-storyboard-is-not-responding

Comment: I think my problem was originally related to something else as I believe there was nothing like storyboards when I asked it ... (possibly, never used them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey I had this same issue. This is old, so maybe you found a solution already, but for those who haven't...

Select the cell in IB, and bring up the size panel (by clicking to it or with command-3). Under size & position, set to frame, and edit the height box there.

Easy, huh. Don't know how we missed this.

Answer (score 4):

The tableviewcell size can be set by dragging the cell frame in the interface builder.
Then implement then tableview delegate tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath for the particular cell you want to have a different height.

Answer (score 2):

I have 3.2 installed and don't have that issue.  Check that you are returning the correct cell height for *heightForRowAtIndexPath*.  So for a cell at section zero, row zero (that uses a custom UITableViewCell), use the height of the cell defined in the XIB:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
        return m_customCell.frame.size.height;
    else
        return 44;
}
```

Comment: I can change this in the code, but I have a problem with resizing of the actual view in IB :(((

Comment: So you are not able to resize the window containing the UITableViewCell in IB?  Not quite clear on what is happening for you.

Answer (score 1):

first tab (Attributes) -> subtab(Simulated User Interface Elements) -> Status Bar: set(Unspecified) .  Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer (selecting the TableCell) and using the inspector did not work for me with XCODE 5.

This worked:
- In interface builder, select the TABLE VIEW (NOT the TableViewCell). 
- Then in inspector (Size Inspector), notice at the top "Row Height". Set that as desired.
- Also notice Section Height can be set here too!

Final note, the table cell can definitely be drag/resized as well.