# How to change NSTableCellView's height when using storyboards in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, tableview, nstablecellview

When I create a non-storyboard OSX app and add a Table View from the Object Library to my main window in Interface Builder, I am able to change the height of an NSTableCellView inside that Table View.
[image: row height is correct when using xib files]
Doing so, automatically changes the TableView's row height (even when I run the app).
[image: Running xib based app]

But when I create a storyboard app and follow the exact same steps (adding Table View, changing cellView's height), the TableView's row height does not change, resulting in the NSTableCellView being cropped when I run the app.[image: Running storyboard based app]

I know you can implement the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, but I'm just wondering why this works when using xib files and stopped working when using storyboards. (I really find it a lot easier to design interfaces graphically instead of writing down arbitrary numbers in a text file.)

Is there something I'm missing here? What is the easiest way of doing this, using storyboards?

Comment: This question is for iOS, but looks like it might be the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615862/custom-cell-row-height-setting-in-storyboard-is-not-responding

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the height in the table view (size inspector -> size style: custom and set row height value).