# How to set tableViewCell's Rows Height

Tags: swift, uitableview

I would like to programmatically change my `tableViewCell`'s Height, 
How can i do so?

My TableView Example:-

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Cell Row Height setting in storyboard is not responding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615862/custom-cell-row-height-setting-in-storyboard-is-not-responding)

Answer (score 4):

In your viewcontroller set the row height via:

```
tableView.rowHeight = 88.8
```

You can also set the row height of an individual row by implementing:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 88.0
    }
    return 44.0
}
```